# How to automatically install an image in taxonomy term field every time I install the module

Tags: 8, hooks

I have a module with a custom taxonomy term called colors. The Colors taxonomy has 1 image field where I can upload a file based on the color names. I wanted the images to be automatically installed every time my module got installed. I think that I need to add a piece of code to my module.install file under hook_install(). How do I achieve this?

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a valid task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of steps to doing this. For our demonstration, let's make a few assumptions:

- The module is called **image_taxonomy**.
- We have only one taxonomy term and one file to worry about.
- The image file is called **color.jpg**.
- The taxonomy term is called **color_red**.
- The image field is called **field_color_image**.
- The image is stored in your module's folder under **/images**.

**Step 1. Make the file publicly available**

The first challenge is to get your module-bound asset (the color.jpg file) into your site's public files as a managed file. An abbreviated version of how to do this is:

```
// $absolute_path_to_file is the absolute server path to /image_taxonomy/images/color.jpg
$contents = file_get_contents($absolute_path_to_file);
$file = file_save_data($contents, "public://color.jpg", FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
$file->setPermananet();
\Drupal::service('file.usage')->add($file, 'image_taxonomy', 'image', $file->id());
```

Now you should have a copy of your **color.jpg** file in your site's `/files` folder.

**Step 2. Assign the file to the term.**

```
// $term is a reference to the color_red taxonomy term.
$term->get('field_color_image')->setValue([
  'value' => $file->id();
]);
$term->save();
```

**Last note**

I would run this code from [hook_modules_installed()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Extension!module.api.php/function/hook_modules_installed/8.8.x), just to make sure that all entities and fields have been installed before attempting to assign your image file. This is highly abbreviated code, so be sure to use proper dependency injection and other best practices in your module.

**References**

- [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
- [file_save_data()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!file!file.module/function/file_save_data/8.8.x)
- [file.usage service](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!file!file.services.yml/service/file.usage/8.8.x)

Comment: hello, thank you for the answer. I did what you told me to do, unfortunately I got an error :   file_get_contents: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Comment: @DeryanThimoti it sounds like you might need to ensure that Drupal has sufficient permissions to access that file. If the file is remote, then this answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47611883/6679439

Comment: thank you Beau, in the end it worked out pretty well! You are a life saver!